# Changing embedded Vimeo video duration and setting new end time in UI through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, vimeo

I currently have a Vimeo video added to my website through an embed code from Vimeo's end. I do not own this video so I can't manually alter it. Originally, I wanted to automatically pause the video at the 1:50 mark for anyone using my site and viewing the video. With help from a wonderful user in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359063/automatically-pause-embedded-iframe-vimeo-video-at-specific-time/72359456#72359456), I have a working script that does just that. But now, I'd like to reflect that change in the UI of the video player. So instead of the video showing "6:34" as the video duration, I want the video UI to show the end of the video being 1:50 (110 seconds as shown in the script below).

Here is the video embed code's HTML:

```
<iframe id="vidz" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/401649410?h=11d74aa27c&amp;portrait=0" width="450" height="253" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

And here is the aforementioned script:

```
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    function foo() {
        
        player.getCurrentTime().then(function(time) {
            console.log('time:', time);
            if(time >= 110){  
                player.pause()
            }
        });
        setTimeout(foo, 1000);
    }
    player.on('play', function() {
        foo();
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to manipulate the video player's UI/timeline to reflect a new endtime of 1:50?